# Can I test if a callback is valid?

Tags: php, function, callback

I'd like to be able to test to see whether or not a callback is valid before I try to call it. Is this possible?

If I call `call_user_func` or `call_user_func_array` with something like `array($this, 'methodThatDoesNotExist')` PHP warns with `[E_WARNING] call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you need is the `is_callable()` function.

From the [PHP Manual on is_callable()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php):

> Verify that the contents of a variable
>   can be called as a function. This can
>   check that a simple variable contains
>   the name of a valid function, or that
>   an array contains a properly encoded
>   object and function name.

(and it also works fine with closures)

Comment: Just to add, if you want to call the callback function you can use call_user_func (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) or call_user_func_array (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).

Comment: Also want to add, you can also do something like `$myvar()` to call a function assigned to a variable.